# Read a Text File skipping Lines that has a TAB Character in them

Tags: c#, delimiter, csv

Hye there! I am totally new to C# and need to know that how can I read a File Line by Line (Skipping those with a Tab Character in them) and them set the text to a RichTextBox!
I have been doing this by:

```
DialogResult result = open_dialog.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string file_name = open_dialog.FileName;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);
    String data;

    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    rich_words.Text = data;

    String line;

    using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        // read each line, ensuring not null (EOF)
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line.Contains('\t'))
                //do nothing
            else
                richbox.Text=line;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am failed to do so! Its sad because i have tried my best and now nothing seems to be done by me!
my sample data is:

vital signs

```
                respirations    
           vital signs  
           vital sign checks    
           vital signs/blood pressure   
               blood pressure observation
               blood pressure
               auscultate blood pressures
               monitor blood pressure
               check blood pressure
               blood pressure gauge
```

monitor

```
           monitor skin color   
           monitor characteristics  
           monitor pulse    
           monitor presence 
           monitor  
           monitor/monitor temperature  
               monitor temperature
               continuous temperature monitoring device
```

check

```
           check body temperature   
           check frequency  
           check pain level 
           special checks   
           check    
           check body temperaturewith
```

The highlighted text above has tab characters so I don't need them. Please suggest any solution for this. I only need the words are like headings: |vital signs|
|monitor| and |check| etc... Can somebody help me please with this?

Comment: Unless the code you posted is different than your actual code, your rich text box will only ever show the last line that doesn't contain a tab: `richbox.Text = line;` You need to **append** each appropriate line to the the rich text box

Comment: no it is not working at all! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DialogResult result = open_dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(open_dialog.FileName);

    StringBuilder() sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Don't set the rich_words.Text = data here because there's no need to.

    string line;
    using (var file = File.OpenText(dialog.FileName)) {
        while ((line == file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.Contains('\t')) {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
            // No need to have an else since we only want to do stuff when the line does not contain a tab.
        }
    }

    // Now that you have all of the text from the file into your StringBuilder, you add it as the text in the box.
    rickbox.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

What you were doing was changing the text in the Textbox every time a line did not contain a tab. You were overwriting everything.

Answer (score 1):

krillgar's answer has already explained why your example does not work, but here is all of your code as a one liner, just for fun:

```
richbox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines(file).Where(l => !l.Contains("\t")).ToArray());
```

Comment: Totally agreed. However, as they said they were brand new to C# and had no other LINQ in their method at all, I didn't want to confuse the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this approach

```
if(Char.IsControl(line[0]))
  //do nothing
else
  richbox.Text=line;
```

Comment: This will still just continually overwrite the text in the richbox with the last line that was read, and not all of the desired data from the file.

Comment: I've seen it.But I don't know why user3115728 accepted my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was curious about the same thing. Maybe we should recommend a "Reject Accepted Answer" feature to the site when the OP does something like this that makes no sense. You should at least get a badge for having an accepted answer that has a negative rating. ;)

Comment: A hat. This should definitely be a hat.